# I use the function "FillConsoleOutputCharacter" but the application stoped working

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to make a console application, so i searched for Windows API, and get this code, but it stoped working when i run it, what should i do?

Source code:

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include <conio.h>  //console  i/o

int main()
{
 HANDLE hOut;
 // 获取标准输出设备句柄
 hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
 // 窗口信息
 CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO bInfo;
 // 获取窗口信息
 GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hOut, &bInfo );

 printf("\n\nThe soul selects her own society,\n");
 printf("Then shuts the door;\n");
 printf("On her devine majority\n");
 printf("Obtrude no more.\n\n");
 _getch();
 COORD pos = {0, 0};
 // 向窗口中填充字符以获得清屏的效果
 FillConsoleOutputCharacter(hOut, ' ', bInfo.dwSize.X * bInfo.dwSize.Y, pos, NULL);
 // 关闭标准输出设备句柄
 CloseHandle(hOut);
 return 0;
}
```

Could someone tell me how to solve? PLZPLZ!!

Comment: *it stoped working* is not a problem description we can use. Did it ever work in the first place? In what way does it now work specifically? Do you get any error messages? If so, what is the exact error message? Your code does no error checking on any of the WinAPI calls at all, which means any and all of them could fail and keep the others that follow from working. Have you read the documentation for those API calls to see what they return when they fail? *PLZPLZ!!* is not a reason for not doing basic debugging yourself.

Comment: `FillConsoleOutputCharacter(/*...*/, NULL);` What do your docs say that `NULL` stands for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing NULL to the `lpNumberOfCharsWritten` parameter of `FillConsoleOutputCharacter()`, but the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/fillconsoleoutputcharacter) says:

> *lpNumberOfCharsWritten* [out]
> **A pointer to a variable** that receives the number of characters actually written to the console screen buffer.

It does not say that NULL is valid for that parameter.  So give it what it wants - a pointer to a variable, eg:

```
DWORD dwNumWritten;
FillConsoleOutputCharacter(hOut, ' ', bInfo.dwSize.X * bInfo.dwSize.Y, pos, &dwNumWritten);
```